# Link prediction with input data

Tags: pandas, numpy, knn

I have a list of files, an I use the KNN algorithm to classify these files.

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(file)
training_samples = get_sample_number(dataset)
X_train = dataset.iloc[:training_samples, 5:9]
y_train = dataset.iloc[:training_samples, 9]
X_test = dataset.iloc[training_samples:, 5:9]

# Feature Scaling
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.fit_transform(X_test)

# Fitting classifier to the training set
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, metric='minkowski', p=2)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Now I have my categories in my y_pred array. But I want to save the result in the file where I read the dataset. How can I link a prediction to the right row in the file (or dataset)?

Answer (score 0):

Your predictions in `y_pred` have a length of `X_test.shape[0]`, which is obviously less than the length of the original `dataset`. If you want to attach the predictions to the original `dataset` that you read from `file`, you would need to make predictions on the whole dataset, and then do a simple `concat` to get it all together:

```
y_pred_all = classifier.predict(dataset.iloc[:, 5:9])

dataset = pd.concat([dataset, y_pred_all], axis=1)
```